# Search and replace in python. replacing content between markers

Tags: python

So I have a code in python for search and replace.

```
fin = open(r'F:\1\xxx.txt')
fout = open(r'F:\1\xxx2.txt', "wt")
for line in fin:
    fout.write( line.replace('foo', 'bar') )
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to tell it to replace anything between a certain set of markers.

Like anything between the number 1111 and 2222 if they appear in the read text file. Replace the whole paragraph that is with another paragraph. My purpose for this is to be able to update code files more effectively.

So say I have similar code files and I updated a certain segment that appears in all of them. Instead of going one By one editing I could write them in advance between markers like:

1111

2222

3333

and then be able to update the paragraph in between.

Anyone has a clue how this can be done?

Comment: Lets start by reviewing [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create an MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: found this software by the way which makes it really easy if its relevant to anyone- nodesoft-searchandreaplce